# Jquery .keypress on a dynamically added input

Tags: jquery, keypress, textinput, dynamic-forms

I am currently adding an input via a .click event and then wanting to listen to any keypress that occurs on this input.  However, the appended  isn't firing any events after it is inserted (i.e. blur, keypress, focus).  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

```
$("#recipientsDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).append('< input type="text" id="toInput" class="inlineBlockElement" style="border:0px none #ffffff; padding:0px; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" />')
    $("#toInput").focus();
});
$("input").keypress(function(e){
    var inputStr = $(this).html();
    $("#inputCopier").text(inputStr);
    var newWidth = $("#inputCopier").innerWidth;
    $(this).css("width", newWidth);
});
$("#toInput").blur(function(){
    $("#toInput").remove();
});
```

I did try .keyup .keydown as well, they don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to capture `blur`/`focus` events, why not add the handler to the created element before adding it to DOM?

```
$('#recipientsDiv').click (function() 
{
    $('< input type="text" id="toInput" class="inlineBlockElement" style="border:0px none #ffffff; padding:0px; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" />')
        .keypress (function (e) { ... })
        .blur (function (e) { $(this).remove () })
        .appendTo ($(this))
        .focus ()
    ;
});
```

Comment: What can i do in complicated scenarios for example when we want to add dynamically more than one element? It seems the better way is using delegated event handling such as On() .

Answer (score 7):

Your `keypress` handler is only being added to the elements that exist when you added it.

You need to call the [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) method to add it to every element that matches the selector, no matter when it was added.

For example:

```
$("input").live('keypress', function(e){
    var inputStr = $(this).html();
    $("#inputCopier").text(inputStr);
    var newWidth = $("#inputCopier").innerWidth;
    $(this).css("width", newWidth);
});
```

Comment: That worked great for the keypress, thank you!  However, it doesn't seem to work for the blur.  According to the documentation it's not supported...

any suggestions?

Comment: Add the handler to the element, before appending to DOM - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment:

As you noticed, the `live` method does not support the `blur` event.

As a workaround, you could manually add the handler every time you add an element, like this:

```
$("#recipientsDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).append('< input type="text" id="toInput" class="inlineBlockElement" style="border:0px none #ffffff; padding:0px; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" />')

    $("#toInput")
        .focus()
        .blur(function(){
            $("#toInput").remove();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!  Sorry for the late response, christmas vacation :-D

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
$("input").live("keypress", function (e) { 
    alert(e.keyChar);
});
```